# Unable to import os in Brython - TypeError

Tags: python, brython

I am trying to import the os module in Brython, but no matter what I do, no matter what I try, I am unable to.
I get the following error (in the Firefox console):

```
"TypeError: obj is undefined for module os" brython.js:6329:21
"message: undefined" brython.js:6330:1
"filename: http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js" brython.js:6331:1
"linenum: 4418" brython.js:6332:1
"Javascript error" TypeError: obj is undefined
Stack-Trace:
$B.get_class@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:4418:5
$test@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:8873:1
$SetDict.__le__@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:8830:50
getattr/method@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:5039:8
$module<@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js line 6329 > eval:966:41
@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js line 6329 > eval:1:14
run_py@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:6329:1
import_py@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:6310:8
import_from_stdlib_static@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:6378:22
$B.$import@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:6454:57
@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js line 3931 > eval:11:1
brython@http://localhost:8000/src/brython.js:3931:7
onload@http://localhost:8000/boolean/boolean.html:1:1
 brython.js:3940:43
"Traceback (most recent call last):
RuntimeError: TypeError: obj is undefined"
```

When I do this:

```
import os

def foo(ev):
    print(os.getcwd())

doc["submit"].bind('click', foo)
```

This is just an example - originally the code was much longer.
I am using the latest Brython version (3.2.0).
The import of os and the functions work fine when I try them on the Brython page in the console they provide, and so far os is the only import that I cannot get to work.
Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time

Update:
It works now, but I have no idea why and I don't understand - if someone could explain what I did wrong that would be great, in case I get a similar problem in the future
I looked around for alternatives to os (I want to read .txt files from a directory - I know how to do this in "vanilla" Python using os) and found a solution using glob, which I tried to import. 
Brython doesn't seem to come with glob, so I put the glob.py in the lib folder - but I also saw that glob imports os, so I wondered if it works, which it did.
Then I tried to import os again, and now it works and I don't know why.

```
from browser import document as doc, alert, html
from glob import glob
import os

# ... # 

def foo(ev):
    print(os.getcwd())

doc["submit"].bind("click", foo)
```

Now works. I don't get it, why does it work if I import glob and then os?

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample `doc` is not defined:

```
import os

def foo(ev):
    print(os.getcwd())

doc["submit"].bind('click', foo)
```

I can `import os` with no issues.

Comment: Hello, yes, this is not the complete code, it works as is though (if I remove the os import and change the foo() function to something like print("hello")). I forgot one line of import, you can see it in my edit: "from browser import document as doc, alert, html", I have that one and the os import. Didn't work before, it works if I change it as per my edit, I don't understand why.

Comment: For me it works only importing `os` and using `foo` as you described (`print(os.getcwd())`). Maybe, if you post the complete code I can provide a better answer.